# Repeat a sub command

Tags: vba, excel

I want to move sheets to a new workbook and save it as a new workbook with the sheet name. I have got that part, but I want to repeat it until all the sheets are moved from the main workbook.

the code I used is below:

```
Sub MoveToNew()
'Move the active sheet to a new Workbook.
Activesheet.Move
MName = Activesheet.Name & ".xls"
MDir = ActiveWorkbook.Path
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\DICS-IN\Desktop\Check\" & MName
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

It works until this but I want the same thing to be repeated until all the sheets are moved and saved separately from the main sheet.

I found Dim as Integer and etc but couldn't do it.

Comment: You need to learn the concept of looping your code, try something [like this](http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Loops.html).

Comment: You cannot remove the last visible worksheet from a workbook.

Answer (score 0):

loop through all sheets using a `For Each ... Next` loop

Example:

```
Sub test()
Dim S As Worksheet

    ' loop through all worksheets
    For Each S In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        Debug.Print S.Name
        ' do something with S
    Next S

End Sub
```